# Arithmetic syntax error with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to call the function "warn" if the calculation is TRUE. I am still not quite comfortable with the syntax, would like some tips on how to fix the last line.

```
    if [ "$noproc" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "WARNING: NoProc at $noproc for $process processes." >> $log

        elif [ "$max" -ge 11 ]; then 
        [ $(($max - $total)) -lt 6 && [ $idle -le $(($max \* 0.25 | bc -l)) ] ] | warn $total $process $max $idle
```

The error I get: line 97: [: missing ` ] '

Comment: Consider using [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/). It will give you a clearer explanation for the parser error.

Comment: Thanks alot ! Looks like a great tool !

Comment: If this really is bash (as tagged), and your script starts with `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh`, you've got much more flexible syntax available. `( max >= 11 ))` is easier to read than `[ "$max" -ge 11 ]`, after all. You could also use `[[ ]]` for an extended test context, which *would* let you use `&&` internally (rather than having that result in the unexpected end of one command and beginning of another).

Comment: BTW, to explain why `|` is the wrong operator -- `foo | bar` runs both `foo` and `bar` at the same time, connecting the output of `foo` to the input of `bar`. By contrast, what you want here is to run `bar` only if `foo` completes successfully -- which a short-circuiting logical AND operator, `&&`, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tagging for this question is correct and you're genuinely using bash (which is to say that your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, or if not started via a shebang you use `bash yourscript` rather than `sh yourscript`), you might as well take advantage of it.

```
# extended bash math syntax
if (( (max - total) < 6 )) && (( idle <= (max / 4) )); then
  warn "$total" "$process" "$max" "$idle"
fi
```

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use `(( ))`, you can still use `[[ ]]`, which gives you a test context with its own extended syntax:

```
# extended bash test syntax
if [[ $((max - total)) -lt 6 && $idle -le $(bc -l <<<"$max*0.25") ]]; then
  warn "$total" "$process" "$max" "$idle"
fi
```

...whereas if you want to be compatible with POSIX sh, you need to **end** the test before you can put in a shell-level logical-AND operator.

```
# corrected POSIX-compliant test syntax
if [ "$((max - total))" -lt 6 ] && [ "$idle" -le "$(bc -l <<<"$max*0.25")" ]; then
  warn "$total" "$process" "$max" "$idle"
fi
```

---

To understand why, let's look at how your original command would parse, if you changed the (utterly incorrect) `|` symbol to `&&` instead:

```
# Equivalent (longer form) of the original code, with pipe corrected to logical-AND
if [ $(($max - $total)) -lt 6; then
  if [ $idle -le $(($max \* 0.25 | bc -l)) ] ]; then
    warn $total $process $max $idle
  fi
fi
```

Note that this is running, **as a single command**, `[ $(($max - $total)) -lt 6`.

`[` is not special shell syntax -- it's just a command. In older shells it was actually `/usr/bin/[`; today, there's also a `[` builtin as well, but other than being faster to execute, it behaves exactly the same way as it would have were it executing the old, external command.

That `[` command expects to be passed a `]` as its last argument, since there's no `]` after the `-lt 6`, you get a syntax error and it exits.

Similarly, your code would then (if the first command succeeded) run `[ $idle -le $(($max \* 0.25 | bc -l)) ] ]`. Here, you have a `[` command passed **two** `]`s on the end; it simply doesn't know what to do with the second one.

Comment: I didn't know i could use more flexible syntax, script do starts with  #!/bin/bash. Thank you for all those explanation, that will help me alot !

Answer (score 0):

- You can't nest `[` invocations. Even if you could, `a && (b) === a && b` in logic.
- You can't use commands in arithmetic expansions.
- Bash's `[[` is safer than `[`.
- Use More Quotes™.

Result:

```
[[ "$(($max - $total))" -lt 6 ]] && [[ "$idle" -le "$(bc -l <<< "$max * 0.25")" ]] | warn "$total $process $max $idle"
```

Comment: I can't think of any reason to use quotes around `$((...))`. An arithmetic expression can never return multiple words.

Comment: @Barmar, it can if IFS contains numeric values.

Comment: @Barmar Shell programming is an ugly business. The simplest things, such as [looping over an arbitrary set of files](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html), turn out to be fiendishly difficult to do reliably and securely. And once you've spent some days debugging bizarre behaviour because quotes are expanded after globs or some \*\*\*\*, you'll appreciate that.

Comment: Although inside `[[`, arithmetic expressions are not subject to word splitting, so that wouldn't be a concern. Since it's `bash`, I wouldn't even bother with `[[` here and use `((` instead.